# How to apply a two different functions on two data sets

Tags: python

I have 2 data set:

```
data = StringIO("""

date   value
24-Jan-16   0.786
25-Feb-16   0.781
29-Apr-16   0.786
15-May-16   0.761
16-Jun-16   0.762
04-Sep-16   0.783
22-Oct-16   0.797
23-Nov-16   0.792
09-Dec-16   0.783
25-Dec-16   0.788
26-Jan-17   0.776
11-Feb-17   0.789
15-Mar-17   0.781
05-Jul-17   0.785
07-Sep-17   0.796

 """)

 df = pd.read_table(data, delim_whitespace=True)
 df.loc[:, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, "date"], format="%d-%b-%y")
y_values = df.loc[:, "value"]
x_values = np.linspace(0,1,len(df.loc[:, "value"]))
```

and

```
  data2 = StringIO("""

  date        value
  09-Oct-17   0.304
  10-Nov-17   0.316
  26-Nov-17   0.636
  12-Dec-17   0.652
  28-Dec-17   0.639
  13-Jan-18   0.623
  14-Feb-18   0.427
  02-Mar-18   0.619
  18-Mar-18   0.608
  19-Apr-18   0.605
  05-May-18   0.625
  06-Jun-18   0.639
  22-Jun-18   0.663
  08-Jul-18   0.64
  24-Jul-18   0.623
  09-Aug-18   0.632
  28-Oct-18   0.736
    """)
  df2 = pd.read_table(data2, delim_whitespace=True)
  df2.loc[:, "date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2.loc[:, "date"], format="%d-%b-%y")
  y_values2 = df2.loc[:, "value"]
  x_values2 = np.linspace(0,1,len(df2.loc[:, "value"]))
```

I am trying to run a linear and seasonal fit line on the first data set and an exponential function for the second set using the defined functions below

```
  # Linear + seasonal fit
  def func2(x, a0, a1, a2, a3):
        return a0 + a1*x + a2*np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + a3*np.cos(2*np.pi*x)
   #exponential
   def func(x,a,b,c):
        return a * np.exp(-b*x+c)

    popt3, pcov = curve_fit(func2, x_values, y_values)
    popt, pcov = curve_fit (func, x_values, y_values)
```

I tried plotting and running the functions using the below script but received an error

```
     popt, pcov = curve_fit (func, x_values2, y_values2)
     plt.plot(df.loc[:, "date"], df.loc[:,"value"] ,"ro",color='green')
     popt3, pcov = curve_fit(func2, x_values, y_values)
     plt.plot(x_values, func2(x_values, *popt3), '-', 
     linewidth=3.0,color='red',label='Linear Model')
     plt.plot(df2.loc[:, "date"], df2.loc[:,"value"] ,"ro",color='red')
     plt.plot(x_values2, func(x_values2, *popt), '-', 
     linewidth=3.0,color='red',label='exponential')
```

Any suggestion or possible error in my script?

Comment: You should include your error in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to plot on the same axis a **numerical range** and a **date range**.

You created `x_values` to be passed into `func`, but when plotting, you should still use `df.loc[:, "date"]`

Try the following:

```
 popt, pcov = curve_fit (func, x_values2, y_values2)
 popt3, pcov = curve_fit(func2, x_values, y_values)

 plt.plot(df.loc[:, "date"], df.loc[:,"value"] ,"ro",color='green')
 plt.plot(df.loc[:, "date"], func2(x_values, *popt3), '-', 
 linewidth=3.0,color='red',label='Linear Model')

 plt.plot(df2.loc[:, "date"], df2.loc[:,"value"] ,"ro",color='red')
 plt.plot(df2.loc[:, "date"], func(x_values2, *popt), '-', 
 linewidth=3.0,color='red',label='exponential')
```

Comment: Thank you. It plots now with no error but my exponential function is just a straight line below my data. But I'm assuming that just me not using the correct function.